# how to position images in even positions

Tags: html, css, image

I'm designing a web UI using CSS + HTML and I'm in need of developing the following design.

[image: sample]

I've designed the stucture as following.

```
<div class="slider-pager-container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="slider-pager" id="slider-pager">
              <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img height="90px" src="/images/slider/thumbs/image_1_thumb.jpg" /></a>
              <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img height="90px" src="/images/slider/thumbs/image_2_thumb.jpg" /></a>
              <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img height="90px" src="/images/slider/thumbs/image_3_thumb.jpg" /></a>
              <a data-slide-index="3" href=""><img height="90px" src="/images/slider/thumbs/image_4_thumb.jpg" /></a>
              <a data-slide-index="4" href=""><img height="90px" src="/images/slider/thumbs/image_5_thumb.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that I want the images to be variable width but a fixed height. I've done that by using the height attribute in the img tab. I've used the following CSS to position the imgs in even positions.

```
.slider-pager{
     display:table;
}
.slider-pager a{
     display:table-cell;
}
```

this does the job but, the parent element is a fixed width of 970px and if the total width of all the imgs is less than that amount, it renders a huge gap in between two images. What I want to achieve is whatever the image width is, ( less than the parent element ) position the img tags in the center of the page. How can I achieve this without using CSS3 properties since I want this to be compatible with IE 6+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.slider-pager{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Like this? - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLpsg/1/)

Comment: div with content class is already a block, so it automatically takes all the width available

Comment: But this fiddle does the job I want! :)

Comment: one more this, what If I have to add a margin to each a tag?

Comment: Then just do `.slider-pager img { margin: 10px; }`. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/bLpsg/2/)